# downloading a blob using java in app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob

how to  download a blob from app engine?? i want to search for a particular blob and thn provide a download link..what i tried is :

```
<input type="text" name="search"> 
<input type="submit" value="SEARCH" > 
<a href="/mygaeproject1">download link</a>
```

where the mygaeprojectServlet file has a url pattern of mygaeproject1....and the contents of the file are:

```
public class ProjectServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService(); 

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
     throws IOException 
  {
    BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));      
    blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);
    BlobInfoFactory blobInfoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();
    BlobInfo blobInfo = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
    resp.setContentLength(new Long(blobInfo.getSize()).intValue()); 
    resp.setHeader("content-type", blobInfo.getContentType()); 
    resp.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 
            blobInfo.getFilename()); 
    blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp); 
  }
}
```

Comment: you are heading in write direction..please go ahead.

Comment: but t doesnt give the blob when i use the link....what to do?

Comment: You need to pass the `blob-key` to the servlet, right? So the link should be `href="/mygaeproject1?blob-key=XXXYYYZZZ"`

Comment: so now i need to retrieve each blobkey value for each file and pass t...right?

Comment: Exactly you need to have value of blobkey to download it.